# E-Mail Sends converting Lead

Tags: marketing-cloud

When using Marketing Cloud Connect theres and object called "E-Mail Sends" within Salesforce. Since we currently only use Leads the E-Mail sends are linked to the link. What would happen if we convert the lead to an Person Account? Will be E-Mails Sends also be transferred to the Person Account?

Comment: Michael, can you please rephrase your query, not very clear. Please explain, what is the issue you are facing.

Comment: Updated it, hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the **Individual Email Sends** stats do not carry over to the resulting Contact / Person Account from a converted Lead. You don't lose that historic tracking information, it just isn't carried over to the new record.

The system will also create a brand new subscriber within the Marketing Cloud if you were to send them another email.

As it relates to Marketing, the only thing I've noticed carry over is the **Email Opt-Out** checkbox.